# Save while loop to array and access later;

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a text file  that contains 3 lines with character strings: `"I`, `"Love"`, `"You"`. How exactly to save while value to array and access later? When I change with array value 0 -2 it returns `"You"`. By default it should be 0 = `"I"`, 1 = `"Love"`, 2 = `"You"`.

This is my code so far.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    FILE *pFile;
    wchar_t *file = L"c:\\test.txt";
    wchar_t line[100];
    wchar_t *output[3];
    int i = 0;
    if (_wfopen_s(&pFile, file, L"r, ccs = UNICODE") == 0)
    {
        while (fgetws(line, 100, pFile))
        {

                output[i] = line;
                i++;
        }

    }

    wcout << output[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you _"save a loop"_? Your question title isn't really helpful to identify the problem.

Comment: `output+i=line;`

Comment: @user0042 sory, if the title is nonsense. what i means is value from while loop into array and access later. thx

Comment: @Ron i edited my question with while. i think with for is invalid ways. but still output You only? what problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`output[0]`, `output[1]` and `output[2]` all point at the value of `line`. The value of `line` changes for every iteration of the loop. To fix, you'll need to save off what was read. There are many ways to do this. The best way depends on your needs. One way is:

```
// Allocate space for each output value
wchar_t output[100][3];

//...
    // Save off the lines into the output
    while (fgetws(output[i], 100, pFile))
    {
            i++;
    }
```

`wchar_t output[100][3]` is a double-dimensioned array. The first dimension is 100, second is 3. So this allocates 3 strings of 100 characters.

Comment: i dont understand "save off what was read" u means. example code will make clear.

Comment: I still confuse. i try to output array[1] that should be Love. but it output LovYou. and i tried to input more character inside text file and array size to output[100][7]. I,Love,You,Some,One,Like,You. when i try to output array[1]. it output all. but it return exactly when i make output[100][100]. keyword to explain this please.

Comment: but i think. first [] is amount character allowed. and the second [] is lengh character is allowed. is there way to make it dynamically like using vector?

Comment: yes, there's many ways to do that. `malloc`, `new`, and `vector` are good ways. Look up "dynamic memory allocation"

Answer (score 0):

First it needs to be `wchar_t *output[3];` to allow for 3 values. However it might be more better to use `std::ifstream`

Comment: Thx for corrected. but i recently focus in win32 api. i dont want to mess with external library. cause i want make it work for future windows both version and bit.